# unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to push strapi docker container to google cloud to use it for google cloud run.

I ran following commands in order to push

`sudo docker tag strapi/strapi gcr.io/project_name/strapi`

To activate service account

`gcloud auth activate-service-account service_user --key-file=service_user.json`

To configure docker
`gcloud auth configure-docker`

To add auth to docker configuration

```
gcloud auth list
                  Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       service_account
        other_account
```

Provided following permissions to service account

1. Container registry service
2. Storage Admin

[ERROR] To push image

````
Using default tag: latest
The push refers to repository [gcr.io/project_name/strapi]
65bc6b54035e: Preparing 
983f2d44d014: Preparing 
a791c7d660b3: Preparing 
76269cc2f2b5: Preparing 
cbff660b7bdc: Preparing 
4f92f3f27665: Waiting 
fdba6a5d9dd7: Waiting 
07700abd910e: Waiting 
edfb8ee7c346: Waiting 
aa817488a0dd: Waiting 
74825a980b6d: Waiting 
1fb0a31fe7c2: Waiting 
unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication```
````

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication

Comment: You use docker to push your image. Docker don't use ADC (Application Default Credential).Therefore you have to follow the link provided in the error to grant Docker the authorisation to access to your Container registry.

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong, I was using ```sudo``` while pushing image which made it look for permissions on sudo user where as my config was in ~/.docker/config.js

Answer (score 3):

The mistake I was doing is using `sudo` with `docker push gcr.io/project_name/image_name`. After removing `sudo` the command worked perfectly.

Comment: But in my case it is not working perfectly